# Replacing string with id using dictionary in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary file that contains a word in each line.

titles-sorted.txt

```
 a&a    
 a&b    
 a&c_bus    
 a&e    
 a&f    
 a&m    
 ....
```

For each word, its line number is the word's id.

Then I have another file that contains a set of words separated by tab in each line.

a.txt

```
 a_15   a_15_highway_(sri_lanka)    a_15_motorway   a_15_motorway_(germany) a_15_road_(sri_lanka)
```

I'd like to replace all of the words by id if it exists in the dictionary, so that the output looks like,

```
    3454    2345    123   5436     322 ....
```

So I wrote such python code to do this:

```
 f = open("titles-sorted.txt")
 lines = f.readlines()
 titlemap = {}
 nr = 1
 for l in lines:
     l = l.replace("\n", "")
     titlemap[l.lower()] = nr
     nr+=1

 fw = open("a.index", "w")
 f = open("a.txt")
 lines = f.readlines()
 for l in lines:
     tokens = l.split("\t")
     if tokens[0] in titlemap.keys():
            fw.write(str(titlemap[tokens[0]]) + "\t")
            for t in tokens[1:]:
                    if t in titlemap.keys():
                            fw.write(str(titlemap[t]) + "\t")
            fw.write("\n")

 fw.close()
 f.close()
```

But this code is ridiculously slow, so it makes me suspicious if I have done everything right.

Is this an efficient way to do this?

Comment: How many keys are there and then how many words are you replacing?

Comment: one thing is that you are calling `readlines` you don't need that, and depending on the version of python you are using, it may result in reading all the file at once, which is not necessary. you can simply use `for l in f:`

Comment: Have you considered using threads and workers? Should speed it up by a factor of the number of worker threads.

Please note: this is not meant to be taken as a comment on the algorithm. Merely a statement that more workers make for faster completion.

Comment: @earnshae this code looks like it is supposed to process each line and each token in the line *in sequence* in order to preserve the order in the output file, so I don't see how you would include threads in that.

Comment: Another thing is that you are writing each token individually. You could improve by writing only lines, or even the complete result at once. I'll post an answer about that

Comment: How slow is slow? Maybe it just takes a long time.

Comment: @njzk2 What you can do is split the file into equal parts and re assemble it once the process is complete, to get things started if out put is required you can begin reading from a named pipe that holds the values of the first chunck of data. This will preserve order.

Comment: You're bottleneck is the .write() method. Only call write at the end, and accumulate the strings you want to write in some buffer (probably list)

Comment: @earnshae yes, that would work, as long as the reassembling is not to slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I suspect this differs based on the operating system you're running on and the specific python implementation (someone wiser than I may be able to provide some clarify here), but I have a suspicion about what is going on:

Every time you call write, some amount of your desired write request gets written to a buffer, and then once the buffer is full, this information is written to file. The file needs to be fetched from your hard disk (as it doesn't exist in main memory). So your computer pauses while it waits the several milliseconds that it takes to fetch the block from the harddisk and writes to it. On the other hand, you can do the parsing of the string and the lookup to your hashmap in a couple of nanoseconds, so you spend a lot of time waiting for the write request to finish!

Instead of writing immediately, what if you instead kept a list of the lines that you wanted to write and then only wrote them at the end, all in a row, or if you're handling a huge, huge file that will exceed the capacity of your main memory, write it once you have parsed a certain number of lines.

This allows the writing to disk to be optimized, as you can write multiple blocks at a time (again, this depends on how Python and the operating system handle the write call).

Answer (score 4):

The write loop contains a lot of calls to `write`, which are usually inefficient. You can probably speed things up by writing only once per line (or once per file if the file is small enough)

```
tokens = l.split("\t")
fw.write('\t'.join(fw.write(str(titlemap[t])) for t in tokens if t in titlemap)
fw.write("\n")
```

or even:

```
lines = []
for l in f:
    lines.append('\t'.join(fw.write(str(titlemap[t])) for t in l.split('\t') if t in titlemap)
fw.write('\n'.join(lines))
```

Also, if your tokens are used more than once, you can save time by converting them to string when you read then:

```
titlemap = {l.strip().lower(): str(index) for index, l in enumerate(f, start=1)}
```

Answer (score 0):

If we apply the suggestions so far and clean up your code some more (e.g. remove unnecessary .keys() calls), is the following still too slow for your needs?

```
title_map = {}

token_file = open("titles-sorted.txt")

for number, line in enumerate(token_file):
    title_map[line.rstrip().lower()] = str(number + 1)

token_file.close()

input_file = open("a.txt")
output_file = open("a.index", "w")

for line in input_file:
    tokens = line.split("\t")

    if tokens[0] in title_map:
        output_list = [title_map[tokens[0]]]
        output_list.extend(title_map[token] for token in tokens[1:] if token in title_map)
        output_file.write("\t".join(output_list) + "\n")

output_file.close()
input_file.close()
```

If it's still too slow, give us slightly more data to work with including an estimate of the number of lines in each of your two input files.

Comment: Removing # of fw.write() calls significantly reduced the speed and now the code runs really fast. Thanks! But I thought `tokens[0] in title_map` and `tokens[0] in title_map.keys()` are equivalent. Is explicitly calling keys() more expensive?

Comment: "in map" is a hash time lookup.  "in map.keys()" depends on the python version.  In Python 2, it's a linear search of a list.  In Python 3 is a query to a dict_keys object which is hash time at best, but maybe something less.